# Shloka of below translation from Devi Bhagvatam Book 11 Chapter 1

Tags: identification-request, devi-bhagavata-purana

I'd like to know the shloka of below translation from Devi Bhagvatam, Book 11, Chapter 1:

> "Nârâyana said :– S’ruti and Smriti are the two eyes of God; the Purânam is His Heart. Whatever is stated in S’ruti, the Smriti and the Purânams is Dharma; whatever else is written in other S’âstras is not Dharma."

I read this wonderful translation by Rickross.

Comment: Are you looking for Sanskrit version of this particular verse?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, yes. this siloka is wonderful to explain the clear relation between Veda and Dharma by Sri Narayana Himself.

Comment: But what is your question? It's unclear TBH

Comment: Also since you already have shared the reference of verse, it shouldn't be hard to locate the Sanskrit verse.

Comment: Have you tried locating it from [Sanskrit book](http://satsangdhara.net/devi/devi11-01.htm)? Or you're looking for Sanskrit book?

Comment: Dear LittleNaruto,oh, I'm sorry to make you confuse.And thank you for your concern. But it seems like I'm going to solve this problem by the information by Mr.Pandya.

Comment: Dear Pandya, Thank you for mercifully giving me a nice information. But I  am not able to understand Sanskrit. Could you tell me which verse number is relating to my inquiring siloka?  I can't  recognize.  So, if you can, could you paste that siloka here, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned translation is for [21st shloka of Devi Bhagvatam: Book 11: Chapter 1](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%A7/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%A7):

> श्रीनारायण उवाच
>
> श्रुतिस्मृती उभे नेत्रे पुराणं हृदयं स्मृतम् ।
>
> एतत्त्रयोक्त एव स्याद्धर्मो नान्यत्र कुत्रचित् ॥ २१ ॥

Comment: Dear YDS, thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. Your mercy solved my problem. Thank you (^o^).